# How to get count for similar identifier in a single column using PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a database with 1069 rows. There's a column called `TRIAL_ID` which has the person's identifier from different location. Following is a sample of the column:

```
TRIAL_ID
OAD001
OAD010
OAD501
ROT002
ROT008
ROT903
JAC3ODF
BA39SD
MK2093
```

If you notice, the first three are from location `OAD` and the second three are from the location `ROT`, and the rest with **no pattern** are from the third location.

What I want to do is show a count for each location. The following is what I tried:

```
select (
    select count(trial_id) from locations where trial_id like 'oad%'),
    (select count(trial_id) from locations where trial_id like 'rot%'),
    (select count(trial_id) from locations where trial_id not like 'rot%' or trial_id not like 'oad%') 
from locations
```

But this shows me the count of `oad` and `rot` correctly but not the third one. Also, it shows the count as many times as the number of rows in the `locations` table.

How can I only get the count for each type?

Comment: Do you want a separate row for each location?

Comment: Just replace `OR` with `AND` operator here: `'.... not like 'rot%' or trial_id not like .....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that your version fails is because the `or` should be `and`.  `not` and boolean logic is tricky.

However, conditional aggregation is a better approach:

```
select sum(case when trial_id like 'oad%' then 1 else 0 end) as oad,
       sum(case when trial_id like 'rot%' then 1 else 0 end) as rot,
       sum(case when trial_id not like 'oad%'  and trial_id not like 'rot%' then 1 else 0 end) as other
from locations;
```

It is better because it scans the table only once for all the calculations.

This query returns the results as a single row with three columns for the counts.  Your version is going to show a separate row for each location, with the counts repeated on each row.

You can also express this with a `group by`:

```
select (case when trial_id like 'oad%' then 'oad'
             when trial_id like 'rot%' then 'rot'
             else 'other'
        end) as location,
       count(*)
from locations
group by (case when trial_id like 'oad%' then 'oad'
               when trial_id like 'rot%' then 'rot'
               else 'other'
          end);
```

This returns the results as (up to) three rows.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use conditional aggregation here:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN trial_id LIKE 'oad%' THEN 1 END) AS oad_cnt,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN trial_id LIKE 'rot%' THEN 1 END) AS rot_cnt,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN trial_id NOT LIKE 'oad%' AND trial_id NOT LIKE 'rot%'
               THEN 1 END) AS other_cnt
FROM locations;
```

Note: I chose to use `COUNT` here rather than `SUM`, because using the former allows us to avoid an explicit `ELSE` condition, thus leaving the code a bit shorter and tidier to read.

Comment: This is also a great solution. I agree with your statement that it's bit short and easier to understand. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

A more generic one?

```
SQL> with test (trial_id) as
  2    (select 'OAD001' from dual union all
  3     select 'OAD010' from dual union all
  4     select 'OAD501' from dual union all
  5     select 'ROT002' from dual union all
  6     select 'ROT008' from dual union all
  7     select 'ROT903' from dual union all
  8     select 'JAC30F' from dual union all
  9     select 'BA395D' from dual union all
 10     select 'MK2093' from dual
 11    )
 12  select case when substr(trial_id, 1, 3) in ('OAD', 'ROT') then substr(trial_id, 1, 3)
 13              else 'no pattern'
 14         end location,
 15         count(*) cnt
 16  from test
 17  group by
 18         case when substr(trial_id, 1, 3) in ('OAD', 'ROT') then substr(trial_id, 1, 3)
 19              else 'no pattern'
 20         end;

LOCATION            CNT
------------ ----------
OAD                   3
ROT                   3
no pattern            3

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong logical operator - you need to count the rows that don't start with `rot` **and** don't start with `oad`. Or, in SQL:

```
trial_id not like 'rot%' AND trial_id not like 'oad%'
// -- Here --------------^
```